# How do you turn off pre-build error checking in Visual Studio 2008 (particularly when working with SSIS)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, error-handling

I'm working on an SSIS package and the error checking is really causing it to lag. If you delete a component in the middle of a large dataflow, the error list gets populated by hundreds of Validation errors and it keeps refreshing every time you try to do anything. I turned on the DelayValidation property for the package, but that doesn't fix it.

Thanks for any help!

-Jason

Answer (score 1):

You have to set DelayValidation for every single object that has a DelayValidation flag.  If you right click on the package name in the solution explorer -> click View Code -> run a find and replace in the document for the following:

```
"DelayValidation">0<
```

Replace with the following:

```
"DelayValidation">1<
```

This will set DelayValidation = True for all nodes.  Save and close the View Code screen.  I don't recommend doing this in general since I find the errors and warnings to be useful, but if you are frustrated by the performance then this will technically solve your problem.